# MonoTouch to XCode Export

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, code-signing

I am bidding on a project where the client wants the mobile app delivered in an XCode project as that they can sign it.

Can I build in MonoTouch, then "Export" to Xcode so that I can deliver that to the client?

My experience is that I can build in MonoTouch in roughly 1/2 the time as I can in Xcode. Mostly due to MonoTouch.Dialog and C#'s framework sugar.

I am using MonoTouch Enterprise 5 and MonoDevelop 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lot depend on the definition of *"export to Xcode"* and I encourage you to clarify this with your client.

If the *technical* requirement is simply to sign the application the know that the code signing step, done with MonoDevelop (or with the **mtouch** command-line tool), is simply calling the **codesign** tool which is provided by Apple. That step is applied on a fully built .app (directory) so anyone should be able (with the right certificates/keys) to sign it (as long as the .plist data match).

There is also some support to (in **mtouch**) to build an Xcode project (see --xcode option) that *could* prove useful. This is something you can (and should) try to ensure it can *as is* match your (client) requirements.

Finally there **could** be ways to create a *dumb* Xcode projects that could be used only to copy and sign files. I'm pretty sure that would be possible with VS.NET/msbuild and MonoDevelop/makefiles - but I don't know Xcode well enough to say if that's a possibility.

Conclusion: the only thing I really don't doubt is that you can make this with MonoTouch[.Dialog]/C# in half the time than other solutions ;-)

Comment: They simply need to sign the app before it goes to the App Store as they hold the production keys. So your first option should work.